# Why is the Emulator in Android Studio not running on older macOS versions any more?

Tags: macos, android-studio

The new version of Android Emulator (29.0.11) is not running on older macOS versions. Does anyone know why? It sais:

```
Emulator: Sorry, "qemu-system-x86_64" can not be run on this version of macOS. Qt requires macOS 10.12.0 or later, you have macOS 10.11.6.
```

Where can I download older versions that run on my macOS version?

Comment: Better upgrade your iOS version.

Comment: Isn't there another possibility? I know I should upgrade my iOS but it is my business MacBook and we always stick to the same iOS version all over the department so I have to wait.

Comment: iOS does not run on a MacBook, iOS runs on an iPhone or other iOS devices.

Comment: I am so sorry for mixing up. But this comment also doesn't help me at all.

Comment: This is important!  Anyone have a solution?  Upgrading my mac is NOT an option!

Comment: Thank you @ScottBiggs. I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: I have attempted to downgrade the emulator (as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284378/624814), but it seems that Android Studio still insists on the error.  Or perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: Try the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848328/android-emulator-not-working-on-mac) and especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311288/165358).

Answer (score 0):

The StackOverflow post
[Android Emulator not working on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848328/android-emulator-not-working-on-mac)
seems to address the same problem.

Among the various answers, the one that most fits your case may be the one by
[Tina Zh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848328/android-emulator-not-working-on-mac/44311288#44311288).

I reproduce this answer below:

> On my old Mac (mid 2010 2,8Ghz i5) I had same problem and I want to
>   share my solution with community for future use:
>
> 1. Uninstall all AVD from list.
> 2. Download last version of HAXM  https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x
> 3. Install it manually (it will uninstall previous version automatically by request)
> 4. Generate new AVD for x86 image.

According to an upvoted comment below this answer, this may also be helpful
for newer Macs:

> Fixed my problem. I bought a new Mac and it would seem to be necessary to re-install HAXM even if you've restored from a Time Machine backup. When I opened the Intel Installer it did warn me that HAXM was already installed but I went ahead anyway and my emulator returned to life.

Comment: This could be useful for some people (the link is dead, but it does provide a base for searches), but it doesn't work in my case.  My computer is only a few years old, but I am using Yosemite.  Upgrading to High Sierra will break several valuable tools that are no longer maintained.

Comment: The link still exists on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170714071346/https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x). This link is from a date very near to that answer, and contains other links which are converted to point within the Wayback Machine. I don't know if you should look for the old download or use the latest one from Intel. You will have to test it yourself.